# Should I create a new Model for a filtered view of Existing model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc5

I am new to MVC, and just inherited a project that is still in it's early stages.

The scope is a user interface to manage a single SQL table. There is a model that represents the entire table (select * from table). The previous programmer also created several models that represent a single column (select columna from table), and then several more that represent a Distinct view of a few columns together. I don't know if this is best practice or not.

One problem that I have is if I want to add validation on a filed I need to update several models, when in the end its the same field.

Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A filtered view is a view.  Not a model.  A model is what owns state.  Showing that state in different ways is not the job of the model.  That's a view.

That you have the same field existing in several models is a problem.  That field needs one authoritative place to live.  It's state there is what it IS.  Everything else is just a peek at it, as it was, at one point in time.

There is a lot I could say here but [I've said it before](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/321923/131624).  MVC is just about dividing up responsibility.  There's a lot more to talk about.  How should these parts talk to each other?  Take a look at the observer pattern when you get a chance.