# Writing decision statement on controller layer

Tags: java, rest, mvc, api-design, java8

We are developing a REST application based on an MVC architecture.

The service layer is returning `Optional<T>` where `T` could be any class.

So on the controller layer there is a conditional statement which tests if the result is `Optional.empty`, and then return a custom response with data `[]`; else, return the actual data in a custom Response HTTP response.

```
return ABCService
    .getById("")
    .map("custom response with actual data ")
    .orElse(Collections.empty in Custom response)
    ;
```

Is it a bad practice to write this code in the Controller layer?

We are returning `Optional<T>` because we don't want to send `null`. If we don't use that condition on the Controller layer we have to remove `Optional` returning from service layer too, which I don't think is a good practice.

Can someone please explain why the code above is not good practice? What could be the consequences?

Comment: What is the technical reason for not "sending" a null?

Comment: 'coz **Null References: The Billion Dollar Mistake**

Comment: If you don't like the null, then why not just use null coalescing to remove it instead of going through all this `Optional<T>` business?

Comment: It's said **Null**s are bad, and Optional is the good way to handle it..that's why we are using **Optional<T>**

Comment: I assume you have the ability to think for yourself, eh?

Comment: Yes, indeed... But sometimes we need expert's advise

Comment: Here's what I suggest.  Find out how this problem is commonly solved, and do that.  Normally I don't advocate popularity as a way to make decisions either, but the thing to do in this particular case is probably the thing that most people will recognize as common practice.  I doubt that it's `Optional<T>`.

Comment: @MehrajMalik There is nothing wrong with nulls, your are making life incredibly hard for yourself for no reason, that is the billion dollar mistake here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really depends on how you're doing MVC.  [MVC](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/321923/131624) does not dictate how M, V, and C communicate. Your code makes sense if you're doing [this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/132662/mvc-in-ios-a-modern-approach):

[image]

But not if you're doing [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller):

[image]

Which you should do largely depends on how you feel about [Command Query Responsibility Segregation](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html).

Telling me you're using MVC doesn't tell me much. It's an old design pattern that has been reinvented in many different ways. The only consistent thing about it at this point is the idea of separating 3 areas of responsibility.

---

The billion dollar mistake was to allow `null` into the typing system. Unless you use a language that fixes that you're living with nullable types.

Carefully not returning `null` is a different thing. You avoid returning `null` because the meaning of `null` isn't clear from context to context and the behavior it causes is usually unintended. Returning a [null object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) lets you control the behavior and makes the meaning clear. This can be as simple as setting String to "" rather than `null`.

Using `Optional` lets you get a similar effect without defining a `null` object class because `Optional` is effectively a container. Rather than subjecting you to a `null` that blows up when you dot off of it, `Optional` acts like an ArrayList that contains nothing.

`Optional` doesn't stop `null` from existing. It just abstracts dealing with it away. It effectively stuffs your `if (foo != null)` checks down into `Optional` so you don't have to look at them. It also only works as long as you keep using `Optional`. The moment you break out of `Optional`, and directly touch what's in there, you're right back where you started, dealing with `null`.

Faithfully avoiding `null` in your returns may sound attractive but understand that just because something says it returns `Optional` doesn't mean they can't still screw you and sometimes return a naked `null`. The typing system can't make you that promise. That's the billion dollar mistake.