# What domain objects might I need to represent a user and users profile in a forum web application

Tags: php, mvc, business-logic, model, domain-objects

I’ve been trying to get a firm understanding of the MVC design pattern so that I can write my own framework for implementing the back-end of a forum web application using Slim 3. In particular, after reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5863870/how-should-a-model-be-structured-in-mvc), and asking [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54181162/php-structuring-a-slim3-web-application-using-mvc-and-understanding-the-role-o/54203726#54203726) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58613523/how-should-the-domain-object-and-data-mapper-interact-within-a-service-class-for) question myself I’m now at a point where I think I understand how the model should be a layer composed of data mappers, services and domain objects. However I have some more questions regarding domain objects.

At the moment with a very similar structure from an answer given to [this question I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58613523/how-should-the-domain-object-and-data-mapper-interact-within-a-service-class-for). I have a basic model layer structure for registering a user to my forum application. However it seems to me that my User ‘domain object’ isn’t really doing anything at the moment, it only has getters and setters and I could probably do without it.

User domain object:

```
class User
{
    private $id;
    private $email;
    private $username;
    private $password;

    public function __construct(Email $email, Username $username, Password $password)
    {
        $this->email = $email;
        $this->username = $username;
        $this->password = $password;
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setId(int $id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail(Email $email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;
    }

    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    public function setUsername(Username $username)
    {
        $this->username = $username;
    }

    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function setPassword(Password $password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;
    }
}
```

This user domain object directly mirrors that of my ‘user’ SQL table that is populated when a user registers. In fact this created user domain object is passed to my data mapper then the fields of the passed in user object are extracted and inserted into the database.

Inserting a user object into my ‘user’ table:

```
 private function insertUser(User $user) 
 {
      $sql = 'INSERT INTO users (email, username, password) 
              VALUES (:email, :username, :password)';

      $statement = $this->connection->prepare($sql);
      $statement->execute([':email' => $user->getEmail(),
                           ':username' => $user->getUsername(),
                            ':password' => $user->getPassword()]);

      $user->setId($this->connection->lastInsertId());

      return $user;
 }
```

Could I not just directly pass in the strings that the user typed into the form (after validation and sanitation) instead of having to create this user domain object. It just seems unnecessary at the moment.

This is where I’m confused as to what exactly a domain object should be. I understand they should encompass business logic, but identifying what business logic I would need for a forum application is proving difficult. For example I would like each user to have their own profile page that is publicly visible, that they can only edit and update when the user in question is logged in.

Would I need to create a ‘profile’ domain object together with a new profile table that links to my original user table and user domain object? Or could I simply extend my existing user table and user domain object to have properties and methods that can allow a user to display and update their profile?

I understand this is a matter of design and can be subjective, but some advice on what should be in a domain object (especially for the previous example with a profile) and if they need to marry up to a table or not would be helpful.

A lot of the tutorials I see [such as this](https://github.com/emanuellimeira/PHP-Object-Oriented-Programming-Build-a-Login-System/blob/master/classes/User.php), simply have a single model object that has data mappers methods in them which doesn’t seem right. A lot of tutorials also use frameworks that utilise ORM which is something I’m trying to avoid using as I want to write everything from scratch, although I’m fine with using Slim 3 / 4 PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I’ve been trying to get a firm understanding of the MVC design pattern

[Model View Controller](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/321923/131624) is an impossibly simple pattern. As long as you have something that focuses on the model, the view, and the control then poof you're using MVC. The pattern is so old that no one agrees how those things communicate or how they should be separated. Anything beyond the three responsibilities is just someones idea. The rest isn't standardized. If you want me to understand how your stuff communicates and is separated then you gotta say more than "I use MVC".

> However it seems to me that my User ‘domain object’ isn’t really doing anything at the moment, it only has getters and setters and I could probably do without it.

This isn't a true object oriented object. It's a pile of debugging code (getters and setters) around a data structure. There is no true encapsulation. There is no behavior logic. Does that mean it's useless? No. It's exactly what you need to move data across boundaries in a type safe way (if you don't need type safe just use a collection). But it's no true object. It is a pattern though. It's called a [bean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans). They were invented to make writing persistence frameworks easier. They don't teach you real encapsulation or how to make good objects.

> This user domain object directly mirrors that of my ‘user’ SQL table...

That's exactly why it's not a *domain* object. A *domain* object is not a slave to a repository. It's an independent abstraction in the domain. It represents an idea from the domain, not a mechanical need of the system like persistence.

If it has an ID it's an entity. Entities are allowed to have state that doesn't persist.

If you'll forgive an analogy, persisted entities are freeze dried. Add water and they come to life with new properties and features. Don't insist that they be the same in both forms. It's very useful to have custom transformations from one to the other. It's very hard to have that if you use an ORM.

This is all to say that an entity has a life outside of it's persistence representation.

> Could I not just directly pass in the strings that the user typed into the form (after validation and sanitation) instead of having to create this user domain object. It just seems unnecessary at the moment.

Exactly right. Objects should have a reason to exist. A true object is a bag of functions that change and move together.  You could pass `insertUser()` the user fields it needs and be done. You could also move `insertUser()` into the user class and let it get the fields from object state.

The only reason good to stick with the behaviorless data structure (that bean) is if the data needs to cross a broundry between different systems. A boundary that prevents you from moving behavior (like `insertUser()`) into a proper object.

One of the things object oriented programming has you do is stop moving data around and instead move the behavior (functions/methods) together with that data. Problem is you can't always do that. Sometimes the data needs to move. That's when you fling around data structures.

Comment: Thanks for the answer that’s really helpful, however I have some further questions if you don’t mind?

So really the persistence mechanism should be completely separate from the idea of a domain object? And my user class could be considered a bean instead of a domain object for the pure purpose of moving data from different areas of the program, in this case the database?

Comment: Your domain object (user) should be encapsulated. It's members should be private with no getters. Rather than ask it about it's state you tell it to do things. This works well when you move logic that uses that state into the class. But it breaks down if that logic can't be moved, like with persistence. In that case you ask the domain object to create a bean with the current state. This you can send off to be persisted. That moves the data across the boundary. But no, you don't make the bean into a domain object. You can construct your domain object from a bean and persist it with a bean.

Comment: You say that if the object has an ID it’s an entity. In my case my user object does have an ID. So could my user object be considered a bean and an entity at the same time? And is it the case that entities are basically beans with ID’s? I’m a little confused on that. If beans and true objects are separate, are beans, entities and the persistence mechanism still considered to be part of the model layer?

Comment: If I wanted to create a ‘user’ profile, would it be best to create a proper ‘UserProfile’ domain object that doesn’t directly mirror a database (entity), with state and functionality that can retrieve data from the users table? For things like changing passwords.

Comment: If you wrap your domain object in getters it breaks encapsulation. You can do that, and some people do, but you turn your object inside out because now methods that should be inside the object could be anywhere. Changing existing code becomes really difficult.

Comment: What is considered the model layer is mostly about what is the single authority. Some use the DB as the single authority. In that case the in memory entity is just a state report or a pending update. In other cases the in memory entity is the single authority and the persistence is at best only a report of previous state. In either case the bean exists only when writing or reading the persistence system. Not when making decisions.

Comment: Hi again sorry it’s been a while I’ve been very busy. I have some more questions if you don't mind. My new set of questions is quite long so it might be better if we can open a chat or something, as putting everything into a comment isn't feasable. Let me know if you're happy to do that. And thank you for your replies so far, i'm getting closer and closer to understanding this.

Comment: You can join me in [style](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103949/style)

Comment: Hi, I posted my follow up questions in the chat room you set up, but the chat room seems to have disappeared shortly after. Maybe you could set up another one. Thanks.