# How can I merge between two software architectures in software design?

Tags: design, design-patterns, architecture, agile, system-architecture

I need to know what types can be merged together like can I merge MVC and layered architecture? so please can someone list what types can be merged together, and an example on how to merge.

Can I even merge software architecture?

I am trying to solve a problem, that is asking me to discuss about merging two software styles. As far as I understand just like someone posted that they are abstract definitions of how a software works. So I don't understand how are they supposed to be merged.

Comment: Yes you can. Software is software, each architecture is a trade off between choices that make some things easier, and some things harder. Want to have the best and worst of both worlds? Then hedge your bets, it may pay off, it may go horribly.

Comment: *"I am trying to solve a problem, that is asking me to discuss about merging two software style"* - which kind of problem? An exercise from school? Or a real-world problem? And which two software styles should be mixed, "MVC" and "layered architecture", as you wrote above? Or was that just an example, and you were asked to merge two other styles, or some arbirtrary styles? Please clarify.

Comment: This isn't answerable without more detail about your specific problem.  Normally, you don't "merge software styles," you analyze the problem, strategize the best possible solution given the details of the problem, and implement a solution.  Same process you would use for any other software problem.

Comment: Yes it an exercise. and that was just an example. The question is asking me to discuss how can I merge multiple architecture styles, and the tradeoff of merging them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Software Architecture is the set of (design) decisions that dictate the overall shape of the software. As a software architecture is a set of decisions, it doesn't really make sense to talk about merging two architectures.

However, in making those decisions that form the architecture, you can use multiple architectural styles and/or patterns. I wouldn't really call that merging, but rather that you combine them in an architecture.

And, yes, you can combine the MVC pattern with a layered architectural style in a single architecture. The most common way of combining them is that the Presentation layer contains the MVC Controller and View parts and that the MVC Model part is composed of all the other layers in the architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Layered architecture is MVC. Why? Because [the only consistent requirement for MVC is to have three components focused on three responsibilities](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/321923/131624). If your layered architecture has that it already is [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller).

[Layered architecture](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/software-architecture-patterns/9781491971437/ch01.html) adds rules that dictate what knows about what that MVC doesn’t have. If your MVC code obeys those rules, or can be made to obey them, then sure you can do both.

Before worrying about any of that though ask yourself why you care. Architecture is mostly about what you don’t do. The things you avoid. Doing that is work. It takes effort. Don’t do it without knowing what you get out of it.

Done well, what you usually get is flexible code that can easily accept change. This is good. But don’t kill yourself for it without seeing the value in it.

Comment: I am trying to solve a problem, that is asking me to discuss about merging two software styles. As far as I understand just like someone posted that they are abstract definitions of  how a software works. So I don't understand how are they supposed to be merged.

Comment: @MaroonMark where did you get the idea that they are supposed to be merged?

Comment: The school question is asking me to merge them, and come up with a new architecture.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that this is a real problem, not just a discussion...

You do not merge architectures. Architectures are abstract definitions of how the software would be organized.

What you will do, is to merge software. The equation will be:

> SW 1 (archi 1) + SW 2 (archi 2) = SW 3 (archi 3)

or simplified for visibility:

> SW 1 + SW 2 = SW 3

However, it is almost impossible to have the equation (exceptions may exist):

> archi 1 + archi 2 = archi 3

Therefore, if you really want to have a SW 3, then you need to decide a priori what architecture you want to use, and then re-write the software (re-use allowed) using the respective architecture.

Comment: Nope not  a discussion. I am supposed to merge between multiple software styles, and discuss which software styles can be merged. I've done extensive research which yielded out nothing. except for this. Thanks.

Comment: Well, instead of "merging", start with a brand new architecture. Reuse whatever is worth reusing from the existing architectures.