# How to reuse business logics and resources of different mvc projects from new project

Tags: architecture, architectural-patterns

This new project is kind of fast walk through of previous controllers's jobs but some extra steps in between, sort of working as a wizard.

The thing is, it seems make good sense to create this wizard in the backend as a separate project and manage the states with new database table and manager, yet some of the works best to be delegated to already written codes in different MVC projects.

It doesn't seem best way to send requests to endpoints of each corresponding controller as overall states need to be managed in a centralized way but at the same time want to reuse some of existing business logics in different MVC projects.

What would be the best architecture to achieve this?

I was thinking of creating a service within this new MVC project and somehow delegate each step work to sub-Services under the main service.  Sub-services can be created and use resources of each responsible project and DI injected to the new project's service.  But somehow it still feels a bit inefficient especially how much work will be involved in these new sub-services.

Comment: "overall states need to be managed in a centralized way" overall states of what?

Comment: overall states of the walk through via wizard.  Step1 -> Step2 -> Step3, user can't skip step to go to next step.

Comment: I think we need a better picture of what you're dealing with and what your goals are. Saying it's MVC doesn't tell us much. I've got the impression that there is some existing system with a controller of some kind that you want to replace with a wizard. Why you want to do that is a mystery.

Comment: Many different things get called [MVC](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/321923/131624).